# the proper spot of comma in a sentence

Tags: grammar, commas, context

sample: Humanity has made important discoveries(,) thanks to the development of science and technology, and yet we do not know what exists in the deepest parts of the sea and the universe.

I feel like I need to put a comma in between "discoveries" and "thanks".
which one would it be more proper?

Removing it or putting it in between the words?

Answer (score -2):

The comma is necessary. "Thanks to the development..." is a nonrestrictive clause which adds to your main idea that "humanity has made important discoveries". Without the comma, that sentence would mean

> The reason for humanity making important discoveries is the development of science

And that wouldn't match up with the other bit of your sentence, "and yet we do not know what exists..."

Comment: Would the downvoter mind telling me the reason for the downvote?